# Filter judge to include pitches from 2017 only and select the events column. Store the result in a variable called judge_events_2017

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, methods

I am having trouble with the date. The format of the dates are year-month-day such as '2017-01-01.'
I am fairly new to python and am struggling to find out how to get between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31.' I know this is how I had done it on previous homeworks when I was looking for "after" a certain date. Can I use an "is in between" function? Is "in between" inclusive? Please let me know.

This is what I have:

## All of Aaron Judge's batted ball events in 2017

```
judge_events_2017 = judge[judge['game_date'] >= '2017-01-01']['events']
```

Comment: [df.between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your strings are in a very particular format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`, which means that fortunately the string sorting of dates is equivalent to how they would be sorted as a numeric.  You can obtain all dates in 2017 is a variety of ways (I'd go with the datetime solution).

Also avoid the chained selection, `][`, use `.loc` to select both a subset of rows and columns.

**Explicitly check `<=` and `>=` for between**

```
judge_events_2017 = judge.loc[judge['game_date'].ge('2017-01-01') 
                              & judge['game_date'].le('2017-12-31'), 'event']
```

**Use `Series.between`, just cleans up the above syntax.**

```
judge_events_2017 = judge.loc[judge['game_date'].between('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31'), 'event']
```

**Using string dates check if the first 4 characters are '2017'**

```
judge_events_2017 = judge.loc[judge['game_date'].str[0:4].eq('2017'), 'event']
```

**Convert to a datetime, then use the `year` attribute**

```
judge['game_date'] = pd.to_datetime(judge['game_date'])
judge_events_2017 = judge.loc[judge['game_date'].dt.year.eq(2017), 'event']
```

Comment: So the '.between' function is inclusive in pandas, correct? It will also accept the game_dates='2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31'?

Comment: @radius yes by default it includes the endpoints you can toggle that off with `inclusive=False`. If you need different closure on each end, you'll need to do it separately like in my first example

Comment: Thank you so much!